# Roll back whole query if condition is not met in a single row SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-update

I have to perform an update on a USERPRODUCTS table

```
PRODUCTID  USERNAME     PRODUCTCOUNTRY
 1          A            US
 2          A            UK
 3          B            US
 4          B            CA
 5          B            US
 6          C            IR
 7          F            IR
 8          A            IR
```

I have another table  PERSONCOUNTRY where I know which person can have which country product license only e.g.

```
PERSON         COUNTRYFORPRODUCTLICENSE 
A                    UK
B                    US
C                    IR
```

Now what I want to do is to write a single query to update the table USERPRODUCTS and SET person A to person B such that the query should update only if B has COUNTRYFORPRODUCTLICENSE for ALL rows in USERPRODUCTS for person A otherwise should not update ANY row.

e.g. Person A has PRODUCTCOUNTRY UK, US and IR from above table but B has COUNTRYFORPRODUCTLICENSE only US. So, update query should update row 1 (because B has license for country US) but when it reaches row 2, it should ALL roll back, even the first row it updated.

I know this cannot be handled through single update

```
UPDATE USERPRODUCTS userproducts
SET USERNAME = 'B'
WHERE USERNAME = 'A'
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PERSONCOUNTRY personcountry where    USERPRODUCTS.PRODUCTCOUNTRY IN (US))
```

This query will update only where A has US in  PRODUCTCOUNTRY but will not roll back.

What is the fastest way to do it ? I wanted to do it in a single update query but cannot. Can we use CURSOR to do it ? but I have to do it in Hibernate code

Comment: Is there a way to rollback UPDATE query if any row in the table does not match the condition in where clause ?

Comment: If I follow you right, couldn't you just add a `not exists` clause to your `where`?

Comment: No, it would update all rows where the value is NOT US. What I want is that, in whole table PERSONCOUNTRY , if you find ANY row where USERNAME is 'A' and PRODUCTCOUNTRY is NOT in (US), then do not update table but roll back the whole query / rows which you already updated.

Comment: In pseudo code, update all rows  and SET USERNAME to 'B' where USERNAME = 'A' AND PRODUCTCOUNTRY = 'US' , If any row in table is reached where USERNAME = 'A' and PRODUCTCOUNTRY IS NOT US, then ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

Comment: Basically, it is ASSIGN ALL OR NONE what A has, to B, based on if B HAS productcountries like what A has or not. If A has ANY EXTRA, assign NONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think you can solve this with a `not exists`. From your comments I get the feeling you're thinking row based, but sql works based on sets. When you execute an `update` statement it doesn't update a row and move to the next, it updates all rows that fit the `where` clause.

So something along these lines:

```
    UPDATE USERPRODUCTS
    SET USERNAME = 'B'
    WHERE USERNAME = 'A'
    AND EXISTS (
                 SELECT   NULL 
                 FROM     PERSONCOUNTRY PC 
                 WHERE    PC.COUNTRYFORPRODUCTLICENSE IN ('US') 
                      AND PC.PERSON = USERPRODUCTS.USERNAME
               )
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT   NULL 
                      FROM     PERSONCOUNTRY PC 
                      WHERE    PC.COUNTRYFORPRODUCTLICENSE NOT IN ('US') 
                           AND PC.PERSON = USERPRODUCTS.USERNAME
                  )
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and comment

Comment: shouldn't we use    FROM   USERPRODUCTS PC   
                 WHERE    PC.PRODUCTCOUNTRY IN. It will tell it update only if ALL ROW with USERNAME = 'A' have 'US' in PRODUCT and NOT ANY OTHER country like 'UK'

Comment: But this will make it slow :(

Comment: Adding what I said above made it work! Thanks! you are genius :) I am marking it as answer.

Comment: I used this    UPDATE USERPRODUCTS
    SET USERNAME = 'B'
    WHERE USERNAME = 'A'
    AND EXISTS (
                 SELECT   NULL 
                 FROM   USERPRODUCTS PC   
                 WHERE    PC.PRODUCTCOUNTRY IN ('US') 
                      AND PC.PERSON = USERPRODUCTS.USERNAME
               )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT   NULL 
                      FROM     USERPRODUCTS PC 
                      WHERE    PC.PRODUCTCOUNTRY NOT IN ('US') 
                           AND PC.PERSON = USERPRODUCTS.USERNAME
                  )